# select data between to timestamps

Tags: sql-server

i have a  field in sql name [time] and data are like

```
Checkperson           time
...........................

divye                9:30 AM
nitesh               9:30 AM
abhishek             10:30 AM
 Rajendra            9:30 AM
 ravindra            12:30 PM
 Balwant              11:30 AM
```

i need the data between time stamps 9:30 am to 11:30 am

```
result like 

divye                9:30 AM
nitesh               9:30 AM
abhishek             10:30 AM
Rajendra              9:30 AM
Balwant              11:30 AM
```

Comment: what's your column definition of `[time]`? datetime? varchar?

Comment: its varchar data type

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your time field is a `varchar`, you could convert your `varchar` field to time format (style 114) and use `BETWEEN` operator like this:

```
SELECT  t1.CheckPerson ,
        t1.new_time AS [time]
FROM    ( SELECT    t.* ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT([time], 5))) AS TIME), 114) 
                    AS new_time
          FROM      timetable t
        ) t1
WHERE   t1.new_time BETWEEN '09:30:00.0000000'
                    AND     '11:30:00.0000000'
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle Demo for this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad673/17/0)

**UPDATE**

Based on your query provided in the comments, you could use this in your query like this:

```
SELECT  city ,
        place ,
        [open]
FROM    ( SELECT    city ,
                    place ,
                    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT([open], 5))) AS TIME), 114) 
                    AS [open]
          FROM      staff
        ) q1
WHERE   q1.city LIKE '%%'
        AND q1.place LIKE '%park%'
        AND q1.[open] BETWEEN '10:30:00.0000000'
                      AND     '11:45:00.0000000';
```

Comment: how can i put this on a query like  select * from staff where city like %%'  AND place like '%park%' and [open]between '10:30 AM' and '11:45 am'

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get that. What do you mean by `put this on query`? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: how can i put this on a query like select * from staff where city like %%' AND place like '%park%' and [open]between '10:30 AM' and '11:45 am'

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.

Comment: i ma getting the error Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type TIME is not a defined system type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tablename
where CAST(Created as time) >= '09:30:00' or CAST(Created as time) < '11:30:00'
```

or

```
select * 
from tablename 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Date,108) between '09:30:00' and '11:30:00'
```

Comment: its varchar data type

Comment: i have a column name time where would i pass it, so that it can be converted